# What model is this, that represents Enslavers?

Tags: warhammer-40k, identify-this-game-piece

I spotted this model on a [Bell of Souls article](https://www.belloflostsouls.net/2020/10/warhammer-40k-retro-enslavers-the-galaxys-eldritch-horror-with-rules.html) about Enslavers.

[image: Enslavers models, floating monsters with 6 limbs that end in spikes, with an exposed brain]

But when googling, I can't find the model, and I don't think the article says.

I'm also not sure Enslavers ever had models, so I don't know what else to Google?

What is this model?

Answer (score 5):

That pic/those models first appeared on BoS back in 2007 under the "[Warhammer 30,000 League – Week 3](https://www.belloflostsouls.net/2007/10/warhammer-30000-league-week-3.html)" report. Other pictures in that report also show those figures.

[image]

With the description:

> Balkus
> Alpha Legion, Enslavers
> The Alpha Legion under the command of Master Arkos, scored a hard fought victory for the Imperium upon the lost empire of Balkus. With its fate unknown for over 5000 years, the vile warp-spawned Enslavers have been cast out of this world forever. Captain Arkos has yet again done a service for the Imperium!
> World Status: Compliance

The White Dwarf article in your link is apparently the only source for those rules. The models in the picture seem to have been original/custom.

Comment: I could definitely imagine these are custom models!